# Launching WPF App on Windows 10 with .NET 6 runtime does not work

Tags: wpf, windows-10, .net-6.0

I am publishing a WPF (.NET 6) application with the following settings:

[image]

This works, but if my users want to launch the exe-file on their own PC they get an error message: ".NET 6.0 Runtime is not installed".

[image]

This makes sense to me because .NET 6 is quiet new.
But even after installing the runtime they still get this message (after restarting their PC).

Only if they install the SDK they can launch the app.
But the SDK should only be fore developers?

Am I publishing my app in the wrong way? How can I run .NET 6 apps with only the runtime installed?
My users are all using Windows 10.

Comment: As a workaround, make deployment mode to `Self-contained`.

Comment: Make sure the download the `.NET Desktop Runtime 6`, that one contains the stuff WPF needs. They might have downloaded the `.NET Runtime 6` one instead and that's why your app still showed the error message.

Answer (score 2):

I could resolve my issue with deploying my app as "Self contained". Now the framework is inside the published files.
Everything fine...

However, strange that the initial way did not work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to get the `.NET Desktop Runtime 6` from the Microsoft [download page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0):

[image: Correct runtime example]

Comment: Yeah - thats what I downloaded. The error message appears still even after restarting the PC

Comment: Ok, that's weird... did you try to install the app on a clean Windows installation?

Comment: Well - not sure how "clean" it is. My users having windows 10 installed a long time already...

Comment: And have you tried to install your app on a fresh Windows machine (a new virtual machine, for example)?

Comment: I will try that!